# Electromotor + transformer poor output

Tags: generator

I kindly ask you for help in my project.

Outline: Electromotor used as generator, connected to transformer does not provide expected output; output is lower than input. When connecting the joule thief with a power supply to the same transformer, the voltage amplification is as expected.

Diagram: 
Primary winding of transformer is also connected to the ocilloscope, channel 1. 
[image: Primary winding is also connected to the oscilloscope.]

Picture: 
A picture of the experiment. The generator is rotated with the battery drilling machine.
[image: A picture of the experiment. The generator is rotated with the battery drilling machine.]

DSO output: 
There is more voltage on the primary output than in the secondary output, as can be seen on the picture. 
[image: There is more voltage on the primary output than in the secondary output, as can be seen on the picture.]

**Now, the problem is clear - no voltage transformation, which makes me a very sad puppy, since I will not get rich by manually spinning the generator.**

I have discarded the generator and replaced it with a powered joule thief, just to test the transformer connections and setup.

Picture:

[image: Joule thief + transfomer + DSO, 2 channels.]
Joule thief + transfomer + DSO, 2 channels.

Diagram:

[image: JT + transformer + DSO, 2 channels]

Output: 
This is a good output, the signal gets clearly amplified from the transformer.
[image: This is a good output, the signal gets clearly amplified from the transformer.]

**Questions**:

The transformer is from ATX power supply, MP-EI-33-2

1. What is the cause of the poor tranformation of signal from the electric generator?
2. How can I improve the signal transformation?
3. Isn't the varying signal the best thing you can provide to the transformer????

Thank you in advance,

Kindest regards.

---

I think I have found an answer to the problem:

1. I have opened the electromotor and performed a test with a metallic screwdriver to see if it will jump to any side of the stator.
2. What I have found out is that the magnetic force is very weak. The screwdriver barely goes to left / right side.
3. I would conclude that the **stator does not consist of a permanent magnet** and it requires AC input to switch polarities, which does not happen with the motor being disconnected.

Would this be the correct problem?

Thank you,

Boris.

Comment: Is this 2 questions in one? **Don't do that!** It is very confusing. You seem to be just "trying stuff out" that's fine and how we all started. However, if you want to **learn** what's going on then you have to do your own research. You currently have "ideas" in your head about how things (should) work and then when it doesn't you just jump to the next thing. Regarding the 1st experiment: Why? and what model is the motor, is it even an AC motor? Why the transformer?

Comment: Hi, Bimpelrekkie. Thanks for the comment.

However, the JT sole purpose is to test the transformer and to show that we get the voltage amplification. 

The generator is AC brush from 220V powered electric metal saw. It works and generates voltage, as you can see from first DSO picture - channel 1, which is yellow is from the primary winding, where the generator is connected. The blue channel is secondary, which should be amplified but is not. The transformer would boost up the voltage, which then goes through full bridge rectifier onto a LED light / battery or some other load.

Comment: "AC brush" motor is most probably a universal series or parallel magnetized commutated motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to generate electricity using a universal motor.

[image]

*Figure 1. A universal motor features series connected field and armature windings. There is no permanent magnet involved. Source: [Electrical Easy](http://www.electricaleasy.com/2014/02/universal-motor-construction-working.html).*

- When connected to DC power the poles will be magnetised as shown (or reversed depending on polarity) and the motor will run as a DC brushed motor.
- When connected to AC the polarity of the magnet reverses on each half-cycle but so does that of the rotor so it continues to spin in one direction.
- To reverse the direction of rotation for DC or AC the connections to the brushes are swapped.

As you have discovered, this motor cannot be used as a generator as it has no built-in magnet. You *could* split out the field windings and apply a little power to them to generate some magnetism. The brushes would then output DC and be useless for your transformer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the beautiful explanation. 20 hours+ have been used to learn a lot. 

Best regards.